# What difference does it make including the @package annotation or not?

Tags: php

I am somewhat familiar with the concept of packages in Java, but I'm new to Wordpress and PHP.

In a template file such as `header.php`, what is happening when you include the `@package` notation?

```
<?php
/*
 * @package MyTheme
 */
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Those are PHPDoc tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Inline_Documentation). They are entirely for code documentation purposes.

Comment: The irony is: I thought the asker _knew_ that and wanted to know what _happens_ when it is used.

Comment: @toscho, very plausible interpretation :) I waited several hours after I saw your answer, thinking it would be picked as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will happen. This [PHPDoc tag](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.package.pkg.html) has no special meaning in WordPress, it is not a header WordPress will parse by default. Use it to group your code internally.

`get_file_data()` cannot read it because that function needs a `:` after the identifier (here `package`).